# Migrate jquery 1.7.1 to 2.2.4 and $(document).foundation();

Tags: jquery-migrate

I got this in the console in the Chrome browser.

[Snapshot of the console i Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9myH.png)

I'm trying to upgrade jquery 1.7.1 to 2.2.4 in my mvc site and I use Foundation 5.

I have already got some tip about change ...attr("checked") to ...prop("checked") and that was really nice.

But in this case I don't now what to do...
I suppose that it's wise to something about this "deprecated" code.

In my scripts directory I have jquery-2.2.4.js and jquery-migrate-1.4.1.js

Kind regards
/mique

Comment: To be honest this seems like a strange thing to do. Both jQuery 2 and Foundation 5 are ancient. The compability between Foundation and jQuery als seem shaky. I can find on little information on what version of jQuery Foundation needs. Also jQuery is generally considered out of fashion and unnecessary. My suggestion would be to rewrite the site from the ground up using modern/current libraries (or no libraries at all).

Comment: I have had this in mind, that is, to rewrite som stuff.
Since I like jquery and Foundation, the easiest thing will be to upgrade to Foundation 6 and the latest version of jquery which apparently should work with the latest version of Foundation 6.

To rewrite it in another way will take too much work and time for me and that's not possible.

Honestly, thanks for your honest answer :)
Kind regards
/mique